# shrinkwrapping opposite direction?

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation, shrinkwrap

I'm trying to work out cloth unveil effect with blender, but I cannot get the shrinkwrapping correct. Even if I test it with just a cube, it still turns out flipped, and unchecking 'negative' does nothing..

How can I solve this?[image]

Comment: For an effect like that you will get better looking results with a cloth modifier.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your plane is on the wrong side, try flipping it 180° or flip its normals. But using shrinkwrap probably won't look like you need it to, you should use cloth physics instead.